# UWP C# Custom Event not firing

Tags: c#, xaml, events, win-universal-app

I need someone to tell me what I got wrong... I've read lots of article but can't get my head around the reason the event is not fired.

My Page:

```
 <Grid >
     <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
     <c:customcontrol SavingStarted="ShowProgressBar" />
 </Grid>
```

Code:

```
 private void ShowProgressBar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

My Control:

```
 public delegate void OnSavingStartedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
 public partial class customcontrol : UserControl
 {
     public event EventHandler SavingStarted;

     public virtual void OnSavingStarted (EventArgs e){
        if (SavingStarted != null) {
            SavingStarted(this, e);
        }
     }

     private async void SaveMenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
     OnSavingStarted(EventArgs.Empty);
     //Saves the file

     //will make another event to hide the progressbar
     }

    public ImageWithProgressRing()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }
 }
```

Basically what I intend to do is that when the CustomControl SaveMenuFlyout_Click happens it needs to show a progress bar in the main page...I also intend to make a custom event after to hide the bar after the saving happens

What's wrong and is it the best approach to the problem??

Comment: Are you sure your event isn't fired? The invocation code looks fine. Have you tried setting a breakpoint inside of `SaveMenuFlyoutItem_Click`?

Comment: Yeah that is what im doing and it does not fire

Comment: Yeah I tried my example in a separated project and it worked.... I revise my code because with my short example I made it work ...heheh